# Does google cloud vision API output a confidence level when using character recognition?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am doing OCR using the API of Google Cloud vision.

To make it easier to check the results, I'd like to visualize where we should be more careful and where we should be better off, depending on how reliable the API output is.

I couldn't find it as far as I could, but does the API have the ability to output the confidence level? It would be very much appreciated if you could tell us.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation on text detection in [files](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) and in [images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr), the API does give a confidence score in the response. You can even try it out from there. And there is also the [batch file annotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch) if you would like to try it as well.